mongoose запрос в бд и получение документов с уникальным значением ключча
Есть запрос в БД:
Value.find({ name: req.params.id }, { num: 1, proff: 1, job: 1 })

Вопрос, как в этом запросе получить все документы с уникальным значением ключа num?
При самостоятельном поиске нашел только .distinct(), но он возвращает только значения ключа, а не весь документ.

как в этом запросе получить все документы с уникальным значением ключа num? именно в запосе не получится... Но можно выполнить агрегацию. Выбрать данные по запросу и как-то описать группировку документов по твоему "уникальному" ключу...
